# Typo3 extension views in different windows

Tags: fluid, typo3-extensions

I currently startet a new extension. For this one, it would be very useful to have not all backend views in the same window.
Does anybody known, how to redirecct a view to a different window or open a different view in a different window.
It easy to redirect to another view, but haven't found a way to open it in another window.
I guess, it gives a way, because the extension-builder can be opend in another window.
Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `PHP_OS` constant in your controller file. like below.

in your controller file.

```
/**
 * action list
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function listAction()
{
    $systemOs = PHP_OS;
    $this->view->assign('systemOs', $systemOs);
}
```

Now, use this variables in your fluid template. `List.html` like below

```
<f:if condition="{systemOs} != '' ">
    <f:then>
        <f:if condition="{systemOs} == 'Linux' ">
            <f:then>
                Your layout here
            </f:then>
        </f:if>
        <f:if condition="{systemOs} == 'Window' ">
            <f:then>
                Your layout here
            </f:then>
        </f:if>
    </f:then>
</f:if>
```

Comment: Hi Pravin,
what you mean with 'Your layout here'?
Do you have a example, how I can create a new window or redirect the view to a already created popup window?
To target is still to redirect a view to a different window!

Comment: I mean in this section you need to put your html code.